# Getting permission error on window CLI

Tags: command-line, window

I am running this command on window i.e. `C:\Windows\system32\>netstat` and getting Access is Denied.

So please let me know how can i do this?

Comment: Try : (1) Turning off your antivirus and firewall, (2) Running netstat with full path: `"C:\Windows\System32\netstat.exe"`, (3) Do other commands in `C:\Windows\System32` work correctly?

Comment: (2) Running netstat with full path: "C:\Windows\System32\netstat.exe" :- This is not working.
(3) Do other commands in C:\Windows\System32 work correctly? No
I have run whoami command
and the result was Unknown+User

Comment: Is the Command-Line Interface run as an Administrator?

Comment: Is the Command-Line Interface run as an Administrator?  I Don't know I have a window server on Azure functions.
So please let me know the replacement of sudo for windows.
And how can I run command as root user.

Comment: What is the Version of your _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Server_ Operating System Software Installation?

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows version seems to be in a weird state, and I'm afraid that it would be
impractical to try and find out what are the problems.
I, myself, have never yet heard about such a problem.

I would suggest using an In-place Upgrade in order to ensure that all Windows
components are in a known state.
This would have the same effect exactly as a major Windows update, so the same
precautions are indicated.

Assuming you are on Windows 10, see the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).